# Are these sets precompact in C[0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

a) $x_n(t) = t^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$

b) $x_n(t) = sin(nt), n \in \mathbb{N}$

c) $x_n(t) = sin(t+n), n \in \mathbb{N}$

d) $x_n(t) = sin(at), a \in \mathbb{R}$

e) $x_n(t) = t^n, n \in [1,2]$

f) $x_n(t) = arctan(at), a \in \mathbb{R}$

g) $x_n(t) = e^{t-a}, a \in \mathbb{R}, a \geq 0$

I'm not quite sure how to approach this.  I have written in my notes that every bounded sequence is precompact (Heine Borel Theorem) so I think for b), c), and d), because the sequences are bounded ($-1 \leq sin \leq 1$) that implies that they are precompact.  Similarly, arctan is bounded so the seq in f) is precompact.  For the sequence in a), $t \in [0,1]$ so $x_n$ would be bounded by 1 and therefore precompact.

Is this correct?  It seems too easy.  How would I go about showing precompactness for the rest of the sequences (e, g)?

Comment: The Heine Borel theorem doesn’t apply here (it only applies to sets in $\mathbb R^n$ and very similar spaces). To decide if a collection of continuous functions is compact you probably want to use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Also there are several places where you index the sequence by $n$ but there is a parameter $a$ present. Is this a typo?

Comment: @User8128 Thank you.  so I want to see if there is uniform boundedness and also equicontinuity and that would imply precompactness?  I guess its a typo. Its what it says on my homework, but I'm assuming he meant $x_a$

Comment: Yes, you need to decide which ones are uniformly bounded and equicontinuous.

Comment: @User8128 Thank you again.  I have two questions.  1. How does d) differ from b)?  Is it the same since if its not equicontinuous for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it won't be for $\mathbb{R}$?  2. I think I got it for the first two, but I'm struggling with showing equicontinuity for the third one.  I do think it is equicontinuous, but I'm getting tripped up with the trig.  I took two points t,y s.t. $|t-y|<\delta$, which gives us $|f_n(t) - f_n(y)| = |cosn(sint - siny) + sinn(cost-cosy)|$.  Any idea where to go from here? I tried plugging in some trig formulas, but ultimately got nowhere

Comment: All of them are uniformly bounded except for (g). For equicontinuity, in every case you can use the mean value theorem. You should find that (a), (b), (d), (f) are not equicontinuous (since the derivatives blow up as $n \to \infty$) while (c), (e) are equicontinuous since the derivatives are also uniformly bounded..

Comment: @User8128 Thank you again.  I'm trying to do e) now.  Can you tell me if this is right?  Its uniformly bounded by 1 since $t\in[0,1]$.  Equicontinuity: Let $\epsilon > 0$ and take $\delta = \epsilon/3$.  Since $f_n(t)$ is continuous on [0,1] we can apply MVT.  By the MVT, there is $c\in[t,y]$ (Assume WLOG $t<y$) such that $ \frac{y^n - t^n}{y-t} = f_n'(c) = nc^{n-1} \leq 2$.  Then $y^n - t^n \leq 2(y-t) \leq 2\delta < \epsilon.$

Comment: @User8128 Also probably a stupid question, but for question (g), why isn't it uniformly bounded?  Isn't $e^t$ a bound for all a values since $e^x \leq 1$ for $x\leq 0$?